# Error when trying to run an android app that uses react-native-camera

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

Hi i'm trying to use the camera with react-native-camera in react native but when i run the app it shows this error

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1165 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
> Task :react-native-camera:compileMlkitDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
98 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 96 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-camera:compileMlkitDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-camera:compileMlkitDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

    at makeError (/Users/calebgarcia/Dev/Tibeo/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/calebgarcia/Dev/Tibeo/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/calebgarcia/Dev/Tibeo/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/calebgarcia/Dev/Tibeo/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I've had a lot of problems when trying to run the react native apps on android but in ios they run perfectly.
Do you guys have any idea how can i solve the error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. firstly check whether what jdk version you have installed (got to terminal and check by java --version)
2. make sure u have added that jre path to your environment variables
3. if these condition already u have done then follow below link
   [https://dev.to/larrydanny/could-not-find-tools-jar-4363][1]

your proble will be solved....